# Can an onboard laptop graphics card be replaced with an external one?

Tags: graphics-card, vga, integrated-graphics

I have had a Dell D630 laptop for a long time. Suddenly the graphics card began to over-heat and the screen got a pink color. After a while the monitor didn't show anything.

Right now, when I turn the computer on nothing shows on the screen.

How can I solve this problem? Can I connect an [external USB graphics card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NJFJJK) to replace the onboard graphics card?

[image]

Comment: That's not a graphics adapter... It's simply an extender to your current video card

Answer (score 1):

If you use the USB adapter, there would be no way to get the video to display on the laptop's built in screen. It would work with an external monitor though.